# cannot import 'SelfTrainingClassifier'

Tags: scikit-learn

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.semi_supervised import SelfTrainingClassifier

ImportError: cannot import name 'SelfTrainingClassifier' from 'sklearn.semi_supervised' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/semi_supervised/__init__.py)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please spend a minute to see how to properly format your code & error messages (done it for you this time). Also, this is a pure `scikit-learn` question, and it has nothing to do with `machine-learning`, `deep-learning`, or `artificial-intelligence` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 2):

`SelfTrainingClassifier` is new to version 0.24 (see [0.24 release highlights](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/release_highlights/plot_release_highlights_0_24_0.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-release-highlights-plot-release-highlights-0-24-0-py)).

You can check your current version with `import sklearn; sklearn.show_versions()`.

You can update your version with `pip install --upgrade scikit-learn` or `conda install -c conda-forge scikit-learn`, depending on how you installed the previous version.